# Delete part of the git history

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I would like to delete all my commits older than 3 months on a branch. I would like to know if it is possible and if so, how to do it?

Comment: Is it a single branch (single **tip** that is, not asking if there were many branches in the making of the single branch that I am _ideally_ asking about) that you want to _truncate_?

Comment: In fact, the problem is that I am currently working on a project that is more than 3 years old, and there are files that I would like to delete permanently. So I would like to either delete part of the history on my main branch, or find a way to remove the history referencing of some files in all my branches.

Comment: But why do you want to delete those files? If they are part of the history of the project... well, they are. Unless they made no sense, of course. Anyway, That does not answer my question. I will offer this script for you to consider: https://github.com/eantoranz/git/blob/replay/contrib/replay

Comment: Because these 3 files are deleted for a while from the project, which I am passing on github, and it refuses the files of more than 100MB, and for the moment I can not because of these 3 files